# How to show empty view while opening dashboard home page in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

When running first time the home page dashboard shows project details and selected project name in side menu. here is the screenshot of currently showing [image]

What exactly, I need is [image]

here is the code i used:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
      <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">


          <li class="nav-item">
            <a name="EventDrivenLLC" class="nav-link active" href="#">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="./Cloud Thrifty_files/generic_gcp.png">
              EventDrivenLLC

              <div>
                <small>
                ProjectId:
              </small>
              </div>
            </a>
            </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a name="NickaJack" class="nav-link" href="#">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="./Cloud Thrifty_files/generic_gcp.png">
              NickaJack

              <div>
                <small>
                ProjectId:
              </small>
              </div>
            </a>
            </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a name="NickaJack" class="nav-link" href="#">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="./Cloud Thrifty_files/generic_gcp.png">
              NickaJack

              <div>
                <small>
                ProjectId:
              </small>
              </div>
            </a>
            </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a name="alarmist" class="nav-link" href="#">

              <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="./Cloud Thrifty_files/generic_gcp.png">
              alarmist

              <div>
                <small>
                ProjectId: alarmist-172522
              </small>
              </div>
            </a>
            </li>
```

Details showned while project selected - project listed are listed from side menu, if any of side menu project is selected then it shows the details of project and project is highlighted.

```
      <div id="decodingideas-147616" class="d-none justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom ">
        <h1 class="h2">Project:decodingideas</h1>



    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Compute API Enabled</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Service Account Key</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Other Errors</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
<div class="container">
<h4>Compute Instances (0)</h4>
<table class="table table-striped h6">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Type</th>
    <th scope="col">GCP Zone</th>
    <th scope="col">Startup</th>
    <th scope="col">Shutdown</th>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code more closely. Look where you have:

```
<a name="EventDrivenLLC" class="nav-link active" href="#">
```

And change it to:

```
<a name="EventDrivenLLC" class="nav-link" href="#">
```

I'm not sure this will entirely fix it as I don't see your full coding for that page, but try that first.

Comment: Thanks . Already done that. it just unselect menu but not hiding the selected menu details.

Comment: Is there any sample of it

Comment: Then you'll further need an onclick event on your buttons to show/hide the respective divs. This can be accomplished through javascript for example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp There are other ways as well.